# Matroids and minimal dependent sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Let $M = (E, S)$ be a matroid and $D$ be the set of all minimal dependent sets of $M$. Prove that if $A, B \in D$ with $A \subseteq B$, then $A = B$.

I know that $(E, S)$ is called an independence system, and that according to the definition $S \subseteq 2^E$ and $S$ is closed under inclusion. Also I know that minimal dependent means that if $A \in D$, then every proper subset of $A$ is independent. Any idea about the problem?

Comment: Nothing, I simply don't know how to attack it.

Comment: If $A \neq B$, what are the other possibilities?

Comment: Well, then we can clearly say that $A$ is a *proper subset* of $B$. And because $B \in D$, and $A \subset B$, therefore $A$ is independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: If $A\subseteq B$ and $A\ne B$, then $A$ is a proper subset of $B$. In other words, $A$ is a proper subset of the minimal dependent set $B$. Therefore ... ?

Comment: That's what I just commented above xD. It means that $A$ is independent.

Comment: @portal: That’s right. (Your comment hadn’t appeared when I posted.)

Comment: No problem, it can happen. But, how does it help me exactly? Does independence prove this equality?

Comment: @portal: It gives you the contradiction that you need: it shows that $A$ is *not* a dependent set, contradicting the hypothesis that $A\in D$.

Comment: Oh yeah, now I see it. Thanks!

Comment: @portal: You’re welcome!

Comment: @portal: Will do; it may be a bit, since I’m working on an answer right now, but I’ll take a look.

Comment: Briand, can you check the correctness of my proof here, please. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487821/matroids-and-bases

Comment: @portal: Just did: it’s fine, though I did add a comment.